# Is it possible to Auto-fill input boxes?

Tags: excel, global-variables, inputbox, vba

Allow me to explain the scenario first...

We have a reporting spreadsheet that is capable of updating monthly data for several different measures.

Over time, more and more macros have been added and now total over 20.

To make work a little easier I've added yet another macro, which brings up a user form that

Calls each of the other macros one by one and shows a progress bar to indicate how many tasks (macros) have been completed.

The first 8 macros called upon prompt with an input box for which month is being updated - this will always be the same month across all 8.

SO, what I want to do is add a global input box as the first thing the userform does, then for this input to be referenced in the other macros (having removed their individual prompts).

To be perfectly honest I have absolutely no idea how to do this but have tried the following  (all together).

***In Workbook***

```
Public Monthglobal As Variant
```

***At start of userform code***

```
Function GetMonth()
Monthglobal = InputBox("Please enter the 3 letter abbreviation for the Month which your are updating (e.g. Jan, Feb...)", "Month")
If strName = vbNullString Then Exit Function
End Function
```

***at the start of the userform Sub which calls the macros one by one***

```
GetMonth
```

***Within each of the 8 macros (contained in Module 1)***

```
'Searches for correct column for month and pastes data

Selection.Find(What:=Monthglobal, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
ActiveCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

'Searches for correct column for month and pastes data
```

***Result***

*Run-time error '91':
Object Variable or With block variable not set*

The error is returned with the search (for Variable) section highlighted:

```
Selection.Find(What:=Monthglobal, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
```

I hope thats enough to make sense of it, if anyone needs to see more of the code for the individual macros please gimme a shout but I thought the error message clearly indicates WHERE the issue is...just not WHAT to someone of my lacking experience!

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Could you explain the `If strName = vbNullString` part in `GetMonth()`?

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
Public Monthglobal As String

Function GetMonth()
    Monthglobal = InputBox("Please enter the 3 letter abbreviation for the Month which your are updating (e.g. Jan, Feb...)", "Month")
End Function
```

The search bit - it's better to define what range to search through programatically, rather than using 'Selection'. Will the 3 letter month be the entire cell contents, or just part of it?

```
Dim rngFind as Range, rngFound as Range

Set rngFind = Range("A:A") ' Set this to whatever 'Selection' is currently

'Now set the rngFound variable to be the eventual 'ActiveCell' from your macro above (found cell, offset(1,0))
Set rngFound = rngFind.Find(What:=Monthglobal, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext,MatchCase:=False).Offset(1, 0)

'Now paste without activating anything:
rngFind.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```